# Error en InputFile en .NET Core 5.0 "Cannot read property"

Tags: asp.net-core, component, blazor, spa

estoy intentando replicar la posibilidad de subir archivos tal cual el link que dejo aquí: [post original](https://romansimuta.com/posts/drag-and-drop-file-uploading-with-net-5-0-blazor-inputfile-component/)

La finalidad es procesar el archivo y subirlo a Google Drive (sea imagen, planilla de Excel, documento de Word, archivo PDF, etc)

El código que escribí (tal cual el link de referencia) es:

```
//omití el código de comunicación con Google ya que el error no ocurre ahí
using (var stream = file.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize))
    {
        using (var mstream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            await stream.CopyToAsync(mstream); //acá ocurre la excepción
            request = service.Files.Create(fileMetadata, mstream, file.ContentType);
            request.Fields = "id, webViewLink, iconLink";
            request.Upload();
        }
    }

    var fileResult = request.ResponseBody;
```

La excepción que arroja es:

```
    Cannot read property '_blazorFilesById' of null
TypeError: Cannot read property '_blazorFilesById' of null
    at a (https://localhost:44300/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:69104)
    at s (https://localhost:44300/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:69244)
    at Object.<anonymous> (https://localhost:44300/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:71183)
    at https://localhost:44300/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:68903
    at Object.next (https://localhost:44300/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:69008)
    at https://localhost:44300/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:67920
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at r (https://localhost:44300/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:67665)
    at Object.readFileData (https://localhost:44300/_framework/blazor.server.js:8:71085)
    at https://localhost:44300/_framework/blazor.server.js:1:70043
```

Lo más extraño es que esta excepción ocurre con todos los archivos **menos** con los archivos `.txt`

El `InputFile` que uso es el que viene con Blazor (no uso ningún paquete).

**EDICIÓN 1**

Bajé el proyecto del [post](https://github.com/simutaroman/BlazorUploads) , lo corrí y no me da ninguna excepción (funcionan todos los archivos que me interesan). Por lo que entonces tengo un problema con mi proyecto. Ahora bien, probé cambiando la opción de seleccionar la depuración con IIS Express o  y al seleccionar la segunda opción no me da ninguna excepción. Por lo que concluyo es que tengo un error en mi proyecto cuando lo depuro con IIS Express, pero no sé porque me dá ese error.

Esto es todo lo que tengo. Desde ayer que estoy con este error y no sé como solucionarlo.

Gracias de antemano por cualquier ayuda.
Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa excepción indica que el elemento no existe (es null).

Seguramente estás causando que tu elemento  `InputFile` no se esté renderizando en la página lo cual provoca que el browser limpie los recursos asociados a él.
[github post](https://github.com/SteveSandersonMS/BlazorInputFile/issues/41#issuecomment-692756392)

Comment: Gracias por responder. Fue lo primero que pense, pero pienso: ¿no debería arrojar esa excepción tambien con los archivos .txt que hasta ahora son los únicos archivos que no me dan esa excepción?. Edite mi pregunta con opciones que probé para tratar de aportar más datos.

Comment: Resultaba ser que el ```InputFIle``` estaba condicionado por un código cuando ```InputFileChangeEventArgs``` se disparaba. Básicamente lo escondía. Evidentemente se me pasaba por alto a la hora de buscar la solución. Gracias.